# iPhone-only app isn't iPhone only for some reason

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

In iOS8, when the launch images are specified using a storyboard, I have found that iPhone-only apps do not scale everything correctly. In fact, when an storyboard launch file is used, the iPad won't even use the iPhone asset catalogs and scale them the way it should (with the 1x and 2x on the bottom right). The  app, when a storyboard is used for a launch file, is treated as an iPhone/iPad app regardless of settings specified. Does anyone  know why this is the case?

Comment: This is a known bug in iOS 8. Workaround is not to use storyboards for the launch image until apple fixes it.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Would you mind linking a source? I'm interested in this myself.

Comment: @esqew I don't have a source, I just know other developers who have run into this problem. Including some high profile ones (as in top 10 apps in the store).

Comment: Might be a similar problem / solution as this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817562/black-bars-appear-in-app-when-targeting-ios7-1-or-7-0-in-xcode6