# Xcode 6 simulator to device deformation

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I updated to Xcode 6 recently and just started a new project. I made a project using storyboard and i was testing it in the simulator for the past days. Today i was testing the sound in the app and it wasn't working so i decided to try it on my iPod. This is what the app looks like in the simulator:

[image]

And now here is how it looks on my iPod:

[image]

I didn't use any constraints or anything. The only thing that could have messed it up IMO is the UIProgressView that i made bigger. I don't know if that could have deformed my project on device. Any suggestions to fix it?

ps: I was testing on the iphone 5 simulator and was using an ipod touch 5 to test on device.

Comment: Given how little in the way of details you have provided, you may be disappointed in what answers (if any) you get.

Comment: i have close to no code, i don't know what else i could say except that i made an app in storyboard and it looks fine on the simulator but it's all over the place on device.

Comment: But if we don't know how you constructed it, how can anyone point out what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, i found the issue(s). The deformation was caused by Auto Layout being checked on. The black bars was solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817683/3763526.