# iPhone full height isn't being used

Tags: ios, iphone

I inherited an iOS app and I've found that the full height isn't being used. Here's a pic on the iPhone 6:

[image]

Seems like it's stuck on an iPhone 4 resolution.

iOS deployment target: 7.1

Any ideas how to make the height fit to full screen for the entire app? Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to fit it using autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The default launch screen is not utilizing the full size of the phone.  You may need to create a launch screen first.

- To create the launch screen go to File and then New File.  Under the
  User Interface tab select Launch Screen and save it.
- From here, in your project file, select Targets and then Deployment
  Info.  Under app icons and images, change the Launch Main Screen to
  main.

This should fix your issue!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, follow the below steps:

1. Navigate to project settings
2. Under "App Icons and Launch Images" click on "Use Asset Catalog"
3. Select "Migrate" on the popup that appears.

This should fix the issue.

Here is a link to the reference where I've previously found this answer: [Black bars appear in app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817683/3543861)