# iOS old application screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have old application in iOS and I haven't been involved in development since 1 year.I have built it in iOS 7. Now I open it in XCode 7.1 and its screen size is small and static, like:

[image]

This is UITableview and it has to adjust view to screen accordingly. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this use Autolayout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Comment: Yes I use AutoLayout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black bars appear in app when targeting iOS7.1 or 7.0 in Xcode6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817562/black-bars-appear-in-app-when-targeting-ios7-1-or-7-0-in-xcode6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the various launch screens as mentioned in Image.xcassets

Right Click to add a new iOS launch image set
[image]

And then add the respective launch images

[image]

Comment: the problem is not about images or launch image, It is about view.

Comment: what all launch screens you have added. Have a look at this post. It all starts with launch screens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you need to only drag and drop one image **default-568h@2x.png**

Steps:

after download this image please rename as:"Default-568h@2x.png"

Download image > Drag and drop in Your Project > project Clean and Build > Run

[image: Download from Here]

Answer (score 0):

If your table view is Visible but not fully, then You have set constarint for your tableView.
Thanks...

Comment: If the tableview is in viewcontroller this is true, but in my case it is in tableviewcontoller , so this solution not works

Comment: i tried it my xcode its Working.. i think u  didnt select the tableviewController it is a viewController. if my statement is false, then set background color to tableview and check

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a splash screen with the right size, that is a splash screen with these dimensions:

Width: 640px
Height: 1136px.

This will automatically adjust the view, as it is building for the old 3.5 inch screens `(960px * 640px)` found on the pre-iphone 5 devices.

You should also add splash screens for every other supported screen sizes, namely

- 3.5inches (iPhone 4s and lower)
- 4inches (iPhone 5, 5c and 5s)
- 4.7inches (iPhone 6)
- 5.5inches (iPhone 6 plus)